# context body not working in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

guys, I m new to loopback,  can anybody tell me what I m doing wrong below is my code

```
Permissiontb.assembleAndInsert = async (ctx, cb) => {  
 console.log(ctx.args.data)
 console.log(ctx.res.body)
};

Permissiontb.remoteMethod('assembleAndInsert', {
http: {
  path: '/assembleAndInsert',
  verb: 'post',

},
accepts: [{ arg: 'data', type: 'object', http: { source: 'context' } },

{"arg": "options", "type": "object", "http": "optionsFromRequest"}],
returns: {
  arg: 'data',
  type: 'object',
 },
});
```

now my problem is that if i does console.log(ctx.res.body) i got null can anybody tell me what i m doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [Link](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html)

You can use **ctx.req.body**

**FYI** : You can log **ctx.req** and see all the available data in it.